# format write-output in powershell comma separated

Tags: powershell

I've got a simple powershell script that searches for users that are in a group containing 'www*'. I'd like the output if possible to be

```
samAccountName,Group
```

How would I go about doing that in powershell?

```
$groups = Get-AdGroup -Properties * -filter * | Where {$_.name -like "www*"}
$output = 
    Foreach($g in $groups)
    {
        write-output $g.Name 
        write-output "----------" 
        get-adgroupmember -Identity $g | select-object -Property SamAccountName
    }

$output | out-file -FilePath C:\Users\myuser\desktop\test3.txt -Append
```

Comment: Are you aiming for a strict csv format so that the list can be imported into excel or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$groups = Get-AdGroup -Properties * -filter * | Where {$_.name -like "www*"}
$output = 
    Foreach($g in $groups)
    {
        write-output $g.Name 
        write-output "----------" 
        get-adgroupmember -Identity $g | select-object SamAccountName,@{Name="Group";Expression={$g.Name}}
    }
$output | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Users\myuser\desktop\test3.txt -Append
```

Comment: maybe i didn't ask the question correctly, but that wont solve my issue. I need to iterate through each group, print each username, then the group they belong to, separated by a comma.

Comment: Sorry, reread your question. Hang on, I'll update to provide a solution :-)